# Python remove digits from a list and keeps only words and viceversa

Tags: python

I have this list:

```
my_list = ['11 red', '21 blue', '31 green']
```

And what I'd like to have is something like this:

```
list_n = ['11', '21', '31']
list_w = ['red', 'blue', 'green']
```

Is there a way to save separatly the digits and the words of a list?
I've tried this but it doesn't change anything

```
list_n = [x for x in my_list if not (x.isdigit() or x[0] == '-' and x[1:].isdigit())]
```

Thank you

Comment: If your list contains elements matching a pattern (it seems that your pattern is: "[0-9]+ [a-Z]+", you can try to extract them using regex.

Comment: One-liner: `list_n, list_w = list(map(list, (zip(*[x.split() for x in my_list]))))`

Answer (score 2):

You're overcomplicating it, just split the strings, and take the first and last parts

```
list_n = [x.split(maxsplit=1)[0] for x in my_list]
list_w = [x.split(maxsplit=1)[-1] for x in my_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, You can do whatever you want in single iteration. No need to iterate two times to fill those to lists:

```
my_list = ['11 red', '21 blue', '31 green']
list_n = []
list_w = []

for item in my_list:
    n, w = item.split()
    list_n.append(n)
    list_w.append(w)

print(list_n)
print(list_w)
```

output :

```
['11', '21', '31']
['red', 'blue', 'green']
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try using the split method

```
my_list = ['11 red', '21 blue', "31 green"]
list_n=[]
list_w=[]
for i in my_list:
    x=i.split()
    list_n.append(int(x[0]))
    list_w.append(x[1])
```

Output when you print these lists:

```
[11, 21, 31]
['red', 'blue', 'green']
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't loop twice over the same list, you can do this instead:

```
l1, l2 = [], []
for x in (y.split() for y in my_list): l1 += [x[0]]; l2 += [x[1]]

print(l1, l2, sep='\n')
# ['11', '21', '31']
# ['red', 'blue', 'green']
```

Comment: No need to use dictionary here

Comment: @Sujay;  modified my answer, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to check digit part you can use that code below

```
my_list = ['11 red', '21 blue', '31 green']
list_n = []
list_w = []

for item in my_list:
    for seperate in item.split():
        if seperate.isdigit():
            list_n.append(seperate)
        else:
            list_w.append(seperate)
```

list_n will be = `['11', '21', '31']`

list_w will be = `['red', 'blue', 'green']`